# onLongClickListener crashes

Tags: java, android

I have set an On Long Click Listener on a view that will start an Asyn Task 
but it crashes. I have also set an On Click Listener on the same View and its 
 working properly. My code is as below:
     private View minus Button;

```
 AsyncTask repeatDecrement;
 boolean minusIsPressed=false;  

    public void decrementValue()
       {
          int currentValue=Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());


  if(currentValue>this.minValue)valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentValue-1));      
    }
    minusButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
            {
                minusIsPressed=true;
                repeatDecrement=new repeatDecrement(ValueSelector.this);
                repeatDecrement.execute();
                return false;
            }

        });

    public static class repeatDecrement extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
        ValueSelector object;

        public repeatDecrement(ValueSelector object)
        {
            this.object=object;
        }
        public void onPreExecute()
        {

        }

        public Void doInBackground(Void...voids)
        {
            while(object.minusIsPressed)
                publishProgress();
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
            return null;
        }

        public void onProgressUpdate(Void...voids)
        {
            object.decrementValue();
        }

        public  void onPostExecute(Void unsused)
        {

        }

    }
```

Error log below:

```
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at com.example.customviewgood.ValueSelector$repeatIncrement.doInBackground(ValueSelector.java:1)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-11 12:16:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(24372):    ... 5 more
04-11 12:16:15.430: D/OpenGLRenderer(24372): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-11 12:16:17.830: D/OpenGLRenderer(24372): Flushing caches (mode 2)
04-11 12:16:17.900: D/OpenGLRenderer(24372): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

Comment: write callstack

Comment: could you provide the error log ?

Comment: Post error logs..

Comment: if you cant answer the question dont down vote it please, it will cause stackoverflow to reject my qusestions later

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. I noticed that I was creating my AsyncTask object on the onLongClick event. I created the object in my custom view initializer and it worked.Also I was calling SystemClock.sleep() outside the while loop